# Search engine right indexed multilingual site

Tags: django, internationalization

I have deployed a multilingual site. App detects navigator configurated language and show site in this language, if navigator language is not available then site appears in english.

Also, user can switch to another language with a selector:

```
<li><a href="?lang=da"><span id="flag_da">&nbsp;</span>Dansk</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=de"><span id="flag_de">&nbsp;</span>Deutsch</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=en"><span id="flag_en">&nbsp;</span>English</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=es"><span id="flag_es">&nbsp;</span>Español</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=fr"><span id="flag_fr">&nbsp;</span>Français</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=it"><span id="flag_it">&nbsp;</span>Italiano</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=nl"><span id="flag_nl">&nbsp;</span>Nederlands</a></li>
```

A middleware module is who change language when `lang` is in request.GET

The problem is that I suspect that search engines (google, bing, ...) don't will follow this switch language links and the site will be only indexed in english. And also, in case this links were followed, the same url will have the same content in different language and perhaps this can mislead search engine ( this is guesswork ).

**What can be the most effective changes in this django application to be multilanguage well indexed?**

Notice that this is a django app and I think that this is not an easy work to put language code at begin of each url ( change `http://www.domain.com/some_url` to `http://www.domain.com/en/some_url` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running 1.4.x you can use [i18n_patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) to take care of language spesific urls by turning `http://www.domain.com/some_url` into `http://www.domain.com/en/some_url`(if english is the active language).

Comment: impresive, testing it. Problems:  ` Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: ... ^fr/ ^portal/ productes/$ ... The current URL, fr/portal/productes, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: relekand. I have completed and deployed new code with `http://www.domain.com/en/some_url` pattern! Thanks to you and thanks to django! When I see your answer I have thinked 'it can be as easy' ... but it is. Regards. (Please, try it at http://www.rentit.es/ and say some thing)